# Mongo ids leads to scary URLs

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

This might sound like a trivial question, but it is rather important for consumer facing apps

What is the easiest way and most scalable way to map the scary mongo id onto a id that is friendly?

> xx.com/posts/4d371056183b5e09b20001f9
>
> TO
>
> xx.com/posts/a

M

Comment: You can refer to this post at Google Group: http://groups.google.com/group/mongoid/browse_thread/thread/b4edab1801ac75be/c810df90bb3a2145?lnk=gst&q=incremental#c810df90bb3a2145

Even though it doesn't actually answer your question, it gives you some alternatives to solve the problem.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Define a friendly unique field (like a slug) on your collection, index it, on your model, define `to_param` to return it:

```
def to_param
  slug
end
```

Then in your finders, find by slug rather than ID:

```
@post = Post.where(:slug => params[:id].to_s).first
```

This will let you treat slugs as your effective PK for the purposes of resource interaction, and they're a lot prettier.

Comment: Why not even use the slug for the `_id` field? If it's going to be unique and indexed, there's no need to have both. `_id` isn't limited to the `ObjectId` type.

Comment: I think because mongodb convention is to have real objectids in the _id field.    for example, mongoid used string ids for a while http://www.mongodb.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=16646831 and it caused issues

Comment: what about efficiency? wouldn't searching for long string slug take longer than searching by id?

Comment: @eagor If you are searching on a field, you should index that field. At that point, it should approximately about as expensive as searching for a document with a given ID.

Answer (score 27):

You can create a composite key in mongoid to replace the default id using the key macro:

```
class Person
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :first_name
  field :last_name
  key :first_name, :last_name
end

person = Person.new(:first_name => "Syd", :last_name => "Vicious")
person.id # returns "syd-vicious"
```

If you don't like this way to do it, check this gem: https://github.com/hakanensari/mongoid-slug

Comment: Can't +1 this enough, THANK YOU! (the key thingie)

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, the key macro has been removed from mongo.  For custom ids,
users must now override the _id field.

```
class Band
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :_id, type: String, default: ->{ name }
end
```

Comment: This has a number of gotchas. If you do not set the `name` when instantiating the object (Band.new) you will end up with a nil `_id`. Setting the `_id` afterwards does not work.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a great gem that I've been using to successfully answer this problem: Mongoid-Slug

https://github.com/digitalplaywright/mongoid-slug.

It provides a nice interface for adding this feature across multiple models. If you'd rather roll your own, at least check out their implementation for some ideas. If you're going this route, look into the Stringex gem, https://github.com/rsl/stringex, and acts_as_url library within. That will help you get the nice dash-between-url slugs.

Comment: The url for mongoid-slug leads to a 404 message.

Comment: @JoseCarrilloThanks, fixed it!