# Change the name of the :id parameter in Routing resources for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I looked around on how to change the dynamic params slot and found this post that does the exact thing.
The post is https://thoughtbot.com/blog/rails-patch-change-the-name-of-the-id-parameter-in

Basically what it does is, if following is the routes:

```
map.resources :clients, :key => :client_name do |client|
  client.resources :sites, :key => :name do |site|
    site.resources :articles, :key => :title
  end
end
```

These routes create the following paths:

```
/clients/:client_name
/clients/:client_name/sites/:name
/clients/:client_name/sites/:site_name/articles/:title
```

One solution is to override the `def to_param` method in the model, but I want this without touching the model itself.

But since its for Rails 2.x, how can I achieve the same for Rails 3?

**Update**

This app is using Mongoid. Not AR.
So, the gem friendly cannot be used afaik.

Answer (score 238):

### Rails 4 & 5

In Rails 4, the `:param` option was added, which seems to do exactly what you're looking for. You can take a look at the [Rails 3 code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/e359e3ab935d6790d9a1181e6ebe0038ad168b94/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb#L867) compared to the [Rails 4 code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/e2334a249aa7b9e18d684fd5cf213e78053a9222/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb#L1020).

#### Details

You can easily implement this in your `routes.rb` file:

```
# config/routes.rb

resources :posts, param: :slug

# app/controllers/posts_controller.rb

# ...
@post = Post.find_by(slug: params[:slug])
# ...
```

As of the release of Rails 4, this functionality is [documented in the Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-named-route-parameters).

### Rails 3

Unfortunately, in Rails 3, the `:key` option for `resources` was removed, so you can no longer easily change the name for routes created in this way by just passing in an extra option.

#### Details

I assume you've already somehow gotten the application working the way you want in the past year, but I will go into a way to get the effect you describe in Rails 3 in `routes.rb`. It will just involve a bit more work than the `to_param` method. You can still define custom parameters in routes defined using `scope` and `match` (or it's cousins `get`, `put`, `post`, and `delete`). You simply write in the parameter name you want in the matcher:

```
get 'clients/:client_name', :to => 'clients#show', :as => client

scope 'clients/:client_name' do
  get 'sites/:name', :to => 'sites#show', :as => site
end
```

You would have to manually add all the routes that `resources` automatically creates for you, but it would achieve what you're looking for. You could also effectively use the `:controller` option with `scope` and additional `scope` blocks to take out some of the repetition.

---

**EDIT (May 8, 2014):** Make it more obvious the answer contains information for both Rails 3 & 4. Update the links to the code to go to exact line numbers and commits so that they should work for a longer period of time.

**EDIT (Nov 16, 2014):** Rails 4 should be at the top now and include relevant information as it's been the current version of Rails for quite some time now.

**EDIT (Aug 9, 2016):** Reflect that the solution still works in Rails 5, and update outdated links.

Comment: So basically, Rails3 created the resources option in the router to be restfull, but needs to be overridden for the sake of having custom variable names ... Feels lame!

Comment: Here's a backport of the `param` option for rails 3:

https://gist.github.com/sj26/44ef47fe8b98b46ee32d

Comment: This winds up breaking the url helpers.  They wind up generating a normal id based route if I pass an object in or complaining about a missing [:slug] key if I pass the slug in.  Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: FYI, if you use nested resources, the param for the parent resource will be `post_slug`, which may be confusing.

Comment: I was able to specify the `param` for my nested resources separately (parent vs child). I'm on rails 4.1.0.

Comment: This is really good but what can I do if i do not want parameter name of parent id like post_post_id for nested resource?

Comment: The :slug doesn't seem to take domain names such as example.com. It gives a route error!!

Answer (score 49):

in Rails 4, pass param option to change the :id params. For example
`resources :photos, param: :photo_name` will generate /photos/:photo_name

Answer (score 2):

In Rails 3 you can rename the id keys by using a combination of namespaces and scopes like this (not very nice though):

```rb
namespace :clients do
  scope "/:client_name" do
    namespace :sites do
      scope "/:name" do
         post "/:title" => "articles#create"
         ...
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, what you want is to have the `client_name` instead of `id` in your url, right?

You can do that by overriding the `to_param` method in your model. You can get more information [**here**](http://railscasts.com/episodes/63-model-name-in-url).

Comment: As I already mentioned that I have the constraint of not changing the model. Is the aforementioned example not supported or deprecated in Rails 3?

Answer (score 1):

There's a gem for that, just like there's a gem for everything ;)

I've been using [FriendlyId](http://norman.github.com/friendly_id/) for this kind of behaviour in rails 3.

It will require you to add some code to your model though, like this:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_friendly_id :name
end
```

...and if your clients don't have URI compatible names, you might want to use a slug for that, which you can do with `has_friendly_id :name, :use_slug => true`. When using slugs you'll obviously need to persist them to the database as well though.

And as already mentioned, you can still use the `to_param` trick with rails 3, as documented [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/to_param). I find FriendlyId a bit more versatile though.

Comment: I like friendly id and have used in many projects.
Actually my app is using Mongoid. And friendly_id doesn't support it afaik. And as I already mentioned that my constraint is not to change the model.

Comment: If you're using mongoid, there's [mongoid-slug](https://github.com/papercavalier/mongoid-slug) for achieving this functionality. It actually uses `to_param`, but it does some other clever stuff in the background as well. I found the link here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744446/mongo-ids-leads-to-scary-urls/4970567#4970567

Comment: I liked that gem. There is another similar one [slugoid](https://github.com/crowdint/slugoid). But as I have been saying that I do have the constraint of not modifying the model. That `to_param` breaks my front-end part of the app. Actually I'm looking desperately for the routing approach is I've to change my API but without breaking the Model and Frontend part off the app. Why can't I just have the approach of just modifying the routes only as I'd stated and the example post for older version of rails above???

Comment: Have you tried to rewrite your controllers so it uses your custom route keys? For example `@client = Client.find(:name => param[:client_name]` in `ClientsController#show` ? That might work.

Comment: `Client.where(:name => param[:client_name]).first`, that is.