# Custom parameter name in  RESTful routing, Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change the name of the :id parameter in Routing resources for Rails3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592038/change-the-name-of-the-id-parameter-in-routing-resources-for-rails3)

I'd like to know a clean and elegant way to change the name of paramete in routes, generated by "resources" method. When I check "rake routes", by default I get this:

```
edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)      users#edit
```

But I need to have:

```
edit_user GET    /users/:kitties_and_puppies/edit(.:format)      users#edit
```

To be able later write in controller

```
params[:kitties_and_puppies]
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592038/change-the-name-of-the-id-parameter-in-routing-resources-for-rails3?

Comment: Yep, I've seen. But offered answers did not satisfy me. Overloading of "to_param" method of the model does not affect name of the parameter in the URI at all, it can easily been checked by "rake routes". The adviced gem is nice, but it does much more than requested, for example, it overloads "find" method, which is undesirable in my project for various reasons.
I just need to know the most direct and plain way to change the name of parameter (the :id one), if it exists.
Would be ideal: `resources :user, :key => :my_param_name`.