# Params and selecting the right one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've got this helper method in my application controller:

```
def current_team
    @current_team ||= Team.find(params[:team_id])
end
```

Problem is, it works for urls of the format:

```
/teams/20/members/11
```

but it doesn't work for:

```
/teams/20
```

In order to get it to work for those, I have to change `:team_id` to be `:id`.

How can I tidy it up so it 'just works'?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set instance variables (`@current_team`) in controllers, never in helpers. It's not what helpers are for.

If you follow this advice, you will naturally use `params[:id]` in TeamsController, but `params[:team_id]` in MembersController.

(*Some people even go on to say that you shouldn't use helpers at all. For facilitating presentation (custom links, buttons, tables, etc), they propose to use [Presenter pattern](http://blog.jayfields.com/2007/03/rails-presenter-pattern.html). But you don't have to listen to them. :)*)

Answer (score 0):

It is not the best thing to do, but to accomplish that you can do the following:

```
def current_team
  @current_team ||= Team.find(params[:team_id].presence || params[:id])
end
```

Documentation about the `Object.presence` method:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-presence

---

@SergioTulentsev is right, you shall not set instance variables in helpers, only in controllers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have other resources besides just `Team`.  Rails is going to use the `:id` param for all of your resources.  You will need to look into customizing the routes for your `teams#show` action.  Easier in Rails 4 than in Rails 3.

Have a look at this post for the gory details: [Change the name of the :id parameter in Routing resources for Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592038/change-the-name-of-the-id-parameter-in-routing-resources-for-rails3)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do `params[:team_id] || params[:id]`, because of course in some controller contexts you'd get an `id` parameter that represents the id for something other than a `Team`. Assuming that the `/teams/:id` route is handled by the `TeamsController`, then you could do the following (to keep your method in `ApplicationController` and avoid repeating yourself in different controllers):

```
def current_team
  id = controller_name == "teams" ? params[:id] : params[:team_id]
  @current_team ||= Team.find(id)
end
```

Alternatively, you could change your routes so that the url to show a `Team` is `/teams/:team_id` and leave your helper as-is, but that would go against the grain of Rails routing conventions.