# Single custom param name in routes for nested resources Rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have question about param name for nested resources in rails routes
For example i have:

```
resources :controller1, param: :controller_id do
  resources :controller2
end
```

and i have routes:

```
controller1/:controller_id/
...
controller1/:controller_controller_id/controller2/...
...
```

I want single :controller_id for controller1 
I know it's looks bad, but
How do this?
Thanks!

Comment: I'm in the same situation, how did you solved this issue?

Comment: remove 'param: :controller_id' and you can check route (action) in application controller with use params[:id] or params[:controller_id] for get data

Comment: Facing the same problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the name of the :id parameter in Routing resources for Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592038/change-the-name-of-the-id-parameter-in-routing-resources-for-rails)

Answer (score 19):

how about this:

```
resources :controller1, param: :controller_id do
  member do
    resources :controller2
  end
end
```

will generate

```
GET    /controller1/:controller_id
GET    /controller1/:controller_id/controller2
GET    /controller1/:controller_id/controller2/:id
...
```

Comment: Then you have to fix your nested resource paths helpers, since they will be absolute, `new_controller2_path` instead of `new_controller1_controller2_path`

Answer (score -1):

Try this and see;

```
resources :controller1, param: :controller_id, path: "" do
  resources :controller2, path: ""
end
```

Comment: Thanks but nope, i have controller_controller_id for nested requests again

Comment: @user3049436 Do u want it for the nested resource or parent resource?

Comment: I want it for parent and nested resource, for example: 
controller1/:controller_id
/controller1/:controller_id/controller2/...