# Override nested named route parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Coming from the Rails [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-named-route-parameters), one can simply do this:

```
resources :videos, param: :identifier
```

But, what if I have nested resources? Here are the routes:

```
resources :videos
  resources :images
end
```

The above generate routes like:

```
video_images GET  /videos/:video_id/images(.:format)                  images#index
```

How can I override `:video_id` from the route? I can't seem to be able to use `param` in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `:identifier` instead of `:video_id` you will have to code the routes manually. Which is a pain, so you should really consider why you want non-standard `param` values in your application.

```
get 'videos/:identifier/images', to: 'images#index', as: 'video_images'
```

Note that you'll need to do this for all CRUD routes...

```
get 'videos/:identifier/images/:id', :to => "videos#show", :as => "video_image"
get 'videos/:identifier/images/new', :to => "videos#new", :as => "new_video_image"
post 'videos/:identifier/images', :to => "images#create"
get 'videos/:identifier/images/:id/edit', :to => "images#edit", :as => "ed it_video_image"
put 'videos/:identifier/images/:id', :to => "images#update"
delete 'videos/:identifier/images/:id', :to => "images#destroy"
```

Comment: The reason is that `images` is polymorphic and I wanted to have `imageable_id` as the identifier instead of `video_id` or `audio_id` or whatever. It would be easier to find the parent entity from the `ImagesController`. But thank you, I thought there was a way to override Rails magic on that identifier.

Comment: You can specify the routes twice... nested under video and again under audio.  Then in your controller methods... specifically in a `before_action` that instantiates your objexts... you can test for `params[:video_id]` or `params[:audo_id]`

Comment: Indeed, but it doesn't sound very OOP :) I'll think of some other way, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I will try to enhance an unaccepted answer in linked question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29138733/2405850

try to use nesting with `member` - it will disable default appending for parent resource id.

**However** that will make problems with things that probably we want to preserve like names of helpers. One way to fix this - using `as` (see example below).

Having similar problem I, moreover, still wanted default id for other urls (for example, default videos CRUD or where video is the only possible parent). So I finally I came up with this:

```
resources :videos do
  resources :snapshots
end

resources :videos, param: :imageable_id, only: [] do
  member do
    resources :images, as: 'video_images'
  end
end

resources :users, param: :imageable_id, only: [] do
  member do
    resources :images, as: 'user_images'
  end
end
```

The code above will generate the following routes:

```
    video_snapshots GET    /videos/:video_id/snapshots(.:format)           snapshots#index
                    POST   /videos/:video_id/snapshots(.:format)           snapshots#create
 new_video_snapshot GET    /videos/:video_id/snapshots/new(.:format)       snapshots#new
edit_video_snapshot GET    /videos/:video_id/snapshots/:id/edit(.:format)  snapshots#edit
     video_snapshot GET    /videos/:video_id/snapshots/:id(.:format)       snapshots#show
                    PATCH  /videos/:video_id/snapshots/:id(.:format)       snapshots#update
                    PUT    /videos/:video_id/snapshots/:id(.:format)       snapshots#update
                    DELETE /videos/:video_id/snapshots/:id(.:format)       snapshots#destroy
             videos GET    /videos(.:format)                               videos#index
                    POST   /videos(.:format)                               videos#create
          new_video GET    /videos/new(.:format)                           videos#new
         edit_video GET    /videos/:id/edit(.:format)                      videos#edit
              video GET    /videos/:id(.:format)                           videos#show
                    PATCH  /videos/:id(.:format)                           videos#update
                    PUT    /videos/:id(.:format)                           videos#update
                    DELETE /videos/:id(.:format)                           videos#destroy
       video_images GET    /videos/:imageable_id/images(.:format)          images#index
                    POST   /videos/:imageable_id/images(.:format)          images#create
    new_video_image GET    /videos/:imageable_id/images/new(.:format)      images#new
   edit_video_image GET    /videos/:imageable_id/images/:id/edit(.:format) images#edit
        video_image GET    /videos/:imageable_id/images/:id(.:format)      images#show
                    PATCH  /videos/:imageable_id/images/:id(.:format)      images#update
                    PUT    /videos/:imageable_id/images/:id(.:format)      images#update
                    DELETE /videos/:imageable_id/images/:id(.:format)      images#destroy
        user_images GET    /users/:imageable_id/images(.:format)           images#index
                    POST   /users/:imageable_id/images(.:format)           images#create
     new_user_image GET    /users/:imageable_id/images/new(.:format)       images#new
    edit_user_image GET    /users/:imageable_id/images/:id/edit(.:format)  images#edit
         user_image GET    /users/:imageable_id/images/:id(.:format)       images#show
                    PATCH  /users/:imageable_id/images/:id(.:format)       images#update
                    PUT    /users/:imageable_id/images/:id(.:format)       images#update
                    DELETE /users/:imageable_id/images/:id(.:format)       images#destroy
```

so for every other imageable class you will have to add another ugly construction like above but it should at least preserve other things and act as expected.